The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. How to solve this error?
My connection string is:
"ConnectionString": {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "Data Source = DESKTOP-M39ULR1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = BanglaRunnersDb; Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
}

Here I used this connection string to create DbContext:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString"));
});

When I was trying to run Add-Migration "Initial Migration", I get  an error

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''.

Then I tried using
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString"));
});

before var app = builder.Build();. Then it worked. After that I was trying to execute Update-Database command, and got the error mentioned in the title.
What's the reason behind this error? How to solve it? If more codes is needed to provide just ask me. Any kind of solution is appreciated.

I think your configuration should be ConnectionStrings not ConnectionString

I wasted like 2 hours for this silly mistake. Thank you so much though.


What's the reason behind this error? How to solve it? If more codes is
needed to provide just ask me. Any kind of solution is appreciated.

Based on your scenario and shared code snippet it seems, you have typos within your Database connection string. It should be ConnectionStrings instead of ConnectionString and this is causing the exception while executing the migration command.
In order to resolve your issue you could refactor following code snippet:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "Data Source = DESKTOP-M39ULR1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = BanglaRunnersDb; Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
}


Note: Please refer to this official document if you need complete sample.
